# "Cornered " vs. "being cornered."

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

Should "cornered" or "being cornered" be used in the following? And why?

> He was paralyzed like a rat **cornered/being cornered** by a snake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**Cornered**" alone is better here. You've probably already looked it up, but to "[corner](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corner)" is to trap someone (or, in this case, an animal) in a corner, usually through physical threats. It can also be used figuratively, where it means to put someone in a position or situation that they can't escape from. But I digress.

If a rat is "*being* cornered", it means that the cornering is currently in progress - i.e., the rat is not *yet* cornered, but the process is underway.  The rat, in this instance, would probably be running around with nowhere to go except further into a corner as it futilely tries to get away from the snake. If the rat is "*cornered*", that would mean that it is already trapped in the corner and has nowhere to go, and that's when you'd expect the rat to be paralyzed by fear.

Comment: Good analysis. Thanks.